# How to fetch a csrftoken from a django server?

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I'm reconfiguring my CDN and I want to begin caching pages that use csrf tokens for form submission. Currently, I'm submitting the csrf token with javascript in a post request with:

```
axios.defaults.headers.post['X-CSRFToken'] = getCookie('csrftoken')
```

This works pretty well locally and allowed me to remove the csrf tokens from the templates.

This obviously will not work if I'm accessing cached pages from the CDN. So is it possible for me to fetch a csrf token from the server using Axios and subsequently set it in a post request? If so how do I do this?

An alternative approach would be to disable csrf which I tried already but I couldn't fully disable it. If you are signed into admin csrf protection is automatically enabled even on your frontend forms, I couldn't figure out how to remove this not sure if it's a wagtail or django thing.

I'm using Django 2.2 + Wagtail 2.11.